# Python selenium - Not working in Ubuntu

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Below is the code snippet of what I am running on Ubuntu 16.04.

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    path_to_chromedriver = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver' # change path as needed
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox') 
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    service_log_path = "{}/chromedriver.log".format('/tmp/local/')
    service_args = ['--verbose']
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver,chrome_options=options,
            service_args=service_args,
            service_log_path=service_log_path)
```

Doesnt matter what flag I put, I always get below error in chromedriver.log file.

```
[1.001][INFO]: COMMAND InitSession {
   "capabilities": {
      "alwaysMatch": {
         "browserName": "chrome",
         "goog:chromeOptions": {
            "args": [ "--headless", "--no-sandbox" ],
            "extensions": [  ]
         },
         "platformName": "any"
      },
      "firstMatch": [ {

      } ]
   },
   "desiredCapabilities": {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "goog:chromeOptions": {
         "args": [ "--headless", "--no-sandbox" ],
         "extensions": [  ]
      },
      "platform": "ANY",
      "version": ""
   }
}
[1.001][INFO]: Populating Preferences file: {
   "alternate_error_pages": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "autofill": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "browser": {
      "check_default_browser": false
   },
   "distribution": {
      "import_bookmarks": false,
      "import_history": false,
      "import_search_engine": false,
      "make_chrome_default_for_user": false,
      "show_welcome_page": false,
      "skip_first_run_ui": true
   },
   "dns_prefetching": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "profile": {
      "content_settings": {
         "pattern_pairs": {
            "https://*,*": {
               "media-stream": {
                  "audio": "Default",
                  "video": "Default"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "default_content_settings": {
         "geolocation": 1,
         "mouselock": 1,
         "notifications": 1,
         "popups": 1,
         "ppapi-broker": 1
      },
      "password_manager_enabled": false
   },
   "safebrowsing": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "search": {
      "suggest_enabled": false
   },
   "translate": {
      "enabled": false
   }
}
[1.001][INFO]: Populating Local State file: {
   "background_mode": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "ssl": {
      "rev_checking": {
         "enabled": false
      }
   }
}
[1.001][INFO]: Launching chrome: /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --disable-background-networking --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-component-update --disable-default-apps --disable-hang-monitor --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --disable-web-resources --enable-logging --full-memory-crash-report --ignore-certificate-errors --load-extension=/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.np7aOC/internal --logging-level=1 --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --password-store=basic --remote-debugging-port=12652 --safebrowsing-disable-auto-update --safebrowsing-disable-download-protection --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir=/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.iUR4hY data:,
[1.001][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://127.0.0.1:12652/json/version
[1.002][WARNING]: PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
[927:927:0316/063553.173763:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(90)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.

[1.037][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed
[1.087][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://127.0.0.1:12710/json/version
[1.087][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed
[1.138][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://127.0.0.1:12710/json/version
................................................................
................................................................
[61.031][INFO]: RESPONSE InitSession unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
[61.031][DEBUG]: Log type 'driver' lost 0 entries on destruction
[61.031][DEBUG]: Log type 'browser' lost 0 entries on destruction
```

I tried to run it from non root user as well, but still, I get same error.

I can only SSH to this machine. I tried, if running the command in screen can help but no use, nor does using crontab.

Any guidance will be very helpful.

UPDATE 1:

Below is the chromedriver log after reboot:

```
[1.003][INFO]: COMMAND InitSession {
   "capabilities": {
      "alwaysMatch": {
         "browserName": "chrome",
         "goog:chromeOptions": {
            "args": [ "start-maximized", "--disable-extensions", "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--no-sandbox" ],
            "extensions": [  ]
         },
         "platformName": "any"
      },
      "firstMatch": [ {

      } ]
   },
   "desiredCapabilities": {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "goog:chromeOptions": {
         "args": [ "start-maximized", "--disable-extensions", "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--no-sandbox" ],
         "extensions": [  ]
      },
      "platform": "ANY",
      "version": ""
   }
}
[1.003][INFO]: Populating Preferences file: {
   "alternate_error_pages": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "autofill": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "browser": {
      "check_default_browser": false
   },
   "distribution": {
      "import_bookmarks": false,
      "import_history": false,
      "import_search_engine": false,
      "make_chrome_default_for_user": false,
      "show_welcome_page": false,
      "skip_first_run_ui": true
   },
   "dns_prefetching": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "profile": {
      "content_settings": {
         "pattern_pairs": {
            "https://*,*": {
               "media-stream": {
                  "audio": "Default",
                  "video": "Default"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "default_content_settings": {
         "geolocation": 1,
         "mouselock": 1,
         "notifications": 1,
         "popups": 1,
         "ppapi-broker": 1
      },
      "password_manager_enabled": false
   },
   "safebrowsing": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "search": {
      "suggest_enabled": false
   },
   "translate": {
      "enabled": false
   }
}
[1.003][INFO]: Populating Local State file: {
   "background_mode": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "ssl": {
      "rev_checking": {
         "enabled": false
      }
   }
}
[1.004][INFO]: Launching chrome: /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --disable-background-networking --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-component-update --disable-default-apps --disable-hang-monitor --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --disable-web-resources --enable-logging --full-memory-crash-report --ignore-certificate-errors --load-extension=/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.wpOJGk/internal --logging-level=1 --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --password-store=basic --remote-debugging-port=12725 --safebrowsing-disable-auto-update --safebrowsing-disable-download-protection --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir=/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.XeSkzL data:,
[1.004][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://127.0.0.1:12725/json/version
[1.008][WARNING]: PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
[1752:1752:0321/084842.042837:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(90)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
[1.051][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed
[1.102][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://127.0.0.1:12725/json/version
[1.102][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed
[1.152][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://127.0.0.1:12725/json/version
[1.152][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed
[1.203][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://127.0.0.1:12725/json/version
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all :

```
[455:455:0316/061123.770013:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(90)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
[61.031][INFO]: RESPONSE InitSession unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
```

The error stack trace clearly mentions you were executing the program as a **root** user without **--no-sandbox** argument.

### Solution

Follow the following steps :

- Login as a **non root** user.
- Copy **chromedriver** binary in a more accessible location (e.g. '/usr/local/bin/') and provide the necessary permissions (*chmod 777*)
- Use the following code block :

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

  path_to_chromedriver = '/path/to/chromedriver'
  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument("--headless")
  options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  options.add_argument("--no-sandbox") 
  service_args = ['--verbose']
  service_log_path = '/tmp/local/chromedriver.log'
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/path/to/chromedriver', chrome_options=options, service_args=service_args, service_log_path=service_log_path)
  driver.get('http://google.com/')
  ```

### Trivia

The story of [**Sandbox**](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/design/sandbox.md)

---

### Update A

As you are still seeing the error as :

```
[927:927:0316/063553.173763:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(90)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
```

Try the following steps :

- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

---

### Update B

As per the mandatory [Requirements](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver#requirements) and [#1341](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/1341) ensure the following :

- *Chromedriver* is within `/usr/local/bin/`
- *Chrome Browser* is within `/usr/bin/google-chrome`

About the `[1.008][WARNING]: PAC support disabled` you can safely ignore the log as it is hard-coded in *Chromium Browser Engine* as per the discussion [PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20557708/pac-support-disabled-because-there-is-no-system-implementation)

---

### Update C

As per the Update section in the discussion [**How to make firefox headless programatically in Selenium with python?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753393/how-to-make-firefox-headless-programatically-in-selenium-with-python/46768243#46768243) can you try the **set_headless(headless=True)** method as an alternative as follows :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.set_headless(headless=True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("http://google.com/")
print ("Headless Chrome Initialized")
driver.quit()
```

Additionally have a look at the discussion [**Running Chromedriver on Ubuntu Server headlessly**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500700/running-chromedriver-on-ubuntu-server-headlessly/49505381#49505381)

Comment: As I said, I tried with non root user as well. I tried the code above with another user but it is still giving same error.

Comment: @pratibha Can you update the question with your updated code block and updated error stack trace for further analysis?

Comment: Did you get time to check the updated code and output?

Comment: I can still see `[927:927:0316/063553.173763:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(90)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.`. Can you perform a `cleanup` as per my answer update?

Comment: Its a Ubuntu machine and I have access via SSH only. How can I do cleanup there?

Comment: Atleast try a reboot

Comment: I have asked the client to do so

Comment: I have updated the question with output of chromedriver log.

Comment: Yes both files are there, /usr/bin/google-chrome after few redirections point to /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome

Comment: @pratibha I suppose that's where your program is shows the error. Either change install location or create a direct link.

Comment: I tried that but still same error. I am using non root user as well. I switch user  via `su - newuser`

Comment: @pratibha Can you update the question with your current code trial and the complete error stack trace?