# Can't run Selenium with chromedriver within my ubuntu virtual env

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, path, selenium-chromedriver

I try to run chromedriver in this way :

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--ssl-protocol=any'])
browser.get("whatever-url.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
browser.implicitly_wait(2)
browser.close()
browser.quit()
text_file = open("Output.html", "w") # Write html content on this file for debug purpose
text_file.write(str(soup))
text_file.close()
print("ok")
```

But everytime, I stumble on this error:

```
...
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'chromedriver'
...
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

While chromedriver is very well installed.
Here is why :
[image]
[image]

And running `dpkg -l | less` give me a bit of this:
[image]

I run Python 3.5, Selenium 3.11 and Chromedriver 2.37 on Ubuntu 16 with a virtualenv.

What's wrong :( ?

Please help

Comment: Please, my post is about Chromedriver, not PhantomJS. Any way, I've tried to use Chromedrive path in this way `browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=options, service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--ssl-protocol=any'])`, still get the same error.

Comment: Anyway, the option is the same https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_chrome/selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.html#module-selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver

Comment: `browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/path/to/chromedriver', options=options, service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--ssl-protocol=any'])`

Comment: Already tried this (look my last comment), and I still get the same error

Comment: Does chromedriver have executable rights? What'll you get if you start chromedriver in console inside virtualenv?

Comment: Please how to check if chromedriver has executable? (I'm a newbie in those stuff).

Comment: `ls -l /usr/local/bin/chromedriver` then if permissions have an`x` (rwx, or r-x) then it's executable.

Comment: Also, you can try to put chromedriver in another directory. I store mine in the /opt/chromdriver/ folder

Comment: OK, yes I think it's executable. Here's what I have : `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 54 Apr  1 17:50 /usr/local/bin/chromedriver -> /usr/local/share/chromedriver_linux64/bin/chromedriver`

Comment: @AlexeyDolgopolov I've tried to move in another directory and I get this `error: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed`

Comment: Ok, looks like a progress. Maybe your environment prevented to find chromedriver. Now you may start logging it. Add these to `service_args=["--verbose", "--log-path=webdriver.log"]` And look at the log after crash

Comment: Still get the error :(

Comment: Now what does the log say? You may enable logging in Chromium https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging. `options.add_argument('--enable-logging')   options.add_argument('--log-level=1')` And look in chrome log in the user data directory (in the /tmp folder)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Chromedriver on Ubuntu Server headlessly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500700/running-chromedriver-on-ubuntu-server-headlessly)

Comment: @AlexeyDolgopolov, I've enabled the logging and I can't see logging file in `/tmp` :(

Comment: @DebanjanB your SO post doesn't work for me :(

Comment: I've just reinstalled `google-chrome`, and it works now